# Taking "'int' object is not callable " (Done)

Tags: python, object, math, int

hope you are all in safe. I just wanted to get (20^5)-(1^5)/5(20-1)

```
myNum = ((20**5)-(1**5))/5(20-1)
print(myNum)
```

I took the **TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**
Then I changed it like;

```
print(((20**5)-(1**5))/5(20-1))
```

But I'm still getting same error. I checked the solutions but didn't understand what am I have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix: `((20**5)-(1**5))/5/(20-1)`

Error is that you can't omit multiply sign here: `5(20-1)`.

Interpreter considers you're trying to call function like `f(...)`, but `5` is not a function, that's why you see error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
            ^^^                ^^^^^^^^
             5                  (20-1)
```